# How to read content of spool file?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I have a printer name is Canon LBP3310. It's a share printer, print language is CAPT 3.0, port is USB. I have a program, it send raw data to this printer, I can't edit this program. Spool file's datatype is RAW. So, how to read spool file's content into text file? Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to do that? What exactly you want to modify?

Comment: What do you mean by "reading the file"?  That raw file is just all of the control instructions the printer needs to output the content.  You can simply open the file and look at it with any text editor, but it won't make sense unless you understand the printer's control language.

Comment: I want to do the same thing as GhostScript, but if print language is CAPT then I don't know what should I use.

Comment: If you have a PCL 5 ("raw") print job, give a try with Kyktir ( www.kyktir.info ) the tool is still in development but opens already some basic jobs and files.

Comment: If you just want to extract text, try opening the file with Notepad. However, the file is almost certainly a bitmap, which does not contain any text. For text, use either a PCL5 printer, or use the Generic/Text Only driver. The latter outputs plain text only.

Answer (score 0):

"RAW" in this case means "in printer's control language". That RAW format  is printer-specific, not universal.

You will need a converter for each of the printer control languages (like PCL-5, PCL-XL, PostScript, HP-GL). Example: for PostScript format, you can use GhostScript.

Anyway, after you find the proper control language and you convert the RAW to emf, you can use something like SplViewer or EMFSpoolViewer to view the content.

Either you do that, or try something like [this](https://www.prnwatch.com/ok-printer-viewer/) that can open a lot of the common PCL formats.

Comment: My printer is Canon LBP 3310. It's not use PCL or PostScript. Printer control language of this printer is CAPT 3.0 (driver of this printer).  Spool file is RAW format. I want use a virtual printer to print spool file to become text file. What should I do?

Comment: If CAPSL ( canon print system language) format then what should I use?

Comment: CPCA should be compatible to that. Check my link.

Comment: That's impossible. Error: "Spool file is unknown format". My the spool file generated from sending the print job to the port of a program using the asscembly language. I want to use the API's ReadPrinter() but I do not know when I should use it. Do you know the API?

Comment: If it is PCL5 you can also use Kyktir ( www.kyktir.info )

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question. You can see it below (my approach is different to yours though). [TCP/IP Port printing to TXT File directly from Windows 10 (no additional software)](https://superuser.com/q/1217674/737038)

In any case this is what I have found up till now:
There is an LPDSPOOLER in sourceforge you might try to use (I haven't tried it my self yet but it seems to do the job you are looking for). This is for LPD which I understand will only work with port 9100

https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpdspooler/

And for RAW (which I understand will only work with port 515).

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rawprintserver/

The LPDSPOOLER website shows that it has been used to write print jobs to disk or to a database.

On the other hand, the RAWPRINTSERVER should enable you to install your printer in a Local Port and send print requests to it as if it was a network shared printer. In the case of the RAWPRINTSERVER, I have been thinking if this might also work with the :FILE port (Print to File).

I did not understand from your question if you just want to read the *.spl (Spool File) or edit it prior to sending it to the printer. In any case I think this might help. Do share if you manage to work it out.

Cheers