# TCP/IP Port printing to TXT File directly from Windows 10 (no additional software)

Tags: windows-10, network-printer

I'm trying to create a printer port (in Windows 10) that would let me convert a raw text file sent to this port, to "a Generic Text File" in a virtual printing host scenario.

The idea is that what would normally come out as a sheet of paper from a printer, would now be TXT file that I could import to excel for further use.

Client Description: Industrial Machine capable of LPR through TCP/IP port of Raw Text files.

Windows 10 Machine: Make it work as the LPD by converting the industrial machine printing request into a TXT File that would be saved in "a file" on the Windows 10 machine Hard Drive (with the use of a generic/text only printer driver).

LPD Services are activated on Windows 10 machine

- Printer configuration fields editable on the LPR side:
- Address: IP or Full LPD address (`lpd://host or IP/printer name`)
- Windows Workgroup: Not applicable
- Host user/password for shared printers on host: Not applicable

What I have tried:

1. Local Printer Port / Generic Driver / Shared Printer

   Through this scenario, I'm capable of generating a raw TextFile (print test page) in the "Documents" folder. Sharing though is not working or at least appears to be not working. I did try to change "network account security" in Administrative Tools from `CLASSIC` to `GUEST` just to see if this was a problem. Did not work either.
2. TCP/IP Printer Port / Generic Driver

   Through this scenario, nothing works. I'm giving it a `LOOPBACK IP` given that the Win10 machine is the virtual printer.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you try, but, you might try to use the command line e.g. : "rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \\MyComputer\PrinterName"

Comment: Thank you @GiaRui . Question would this render all other ports un-usable for sharing a local printer on the Win10 machine. For example: If I would share a local printer (USB) with other machines.

Comment: @GiaRui also would there be a way to specify in the command an specific repository (Save File) for the document (TXT File)? Could you explain what are you expecting from the command to be able to do?

Comment: I was thinking you might configure your printer with the mentioned tool, You might try also : prncnfg.vb   ,   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725833%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

Comment: @GiaRui technet.microsoft shows for this command: Add remote printer for a computer which is visible for the user account where this command is run.  Please take note that the printer is not Remote but Local and is expected to work as the FILE: (PrintToFile) Port. So I assume that the reference command will give me a behavior similar to the following: 1. I create a Local "FILE: Port" with a printer named "Printer1". 2. I create an "LPR Port" with the "LOOPBACK IP" as address and "Printer1" as the the "PrinterName". This I have tried and also did not work. Please correct me if assumption wrong.

Comment: @GiaRui . Also There is no routine on the industrial machine that would let me choose the File directory where I would like to put the File (this is how the FILE: port works). If I create a new Local Port the TXT File always ends at the DOCUMENTS folder. But this only works with Case1 of my description. Combinations of Case1 with other methods though, stops the DOCUMENT Folder from receiving the print out, leaving it in the Printer Queue with an ERROR message.